# proving the integral is rational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that $ \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \sin^n x\, dx $ is rational when $n$ is odd given that $n>2$.

I have no idea what tools of calculus should I use to prove this statement. Maybe it's a problem from series. Any kind of  hints that might help me prove this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sh By "the integral" being rational, you mean to prove *that number* is a rational one? Because it isn't already for $\;n=2\;$ : the number in this case is $\;\frac\pi4\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio He said $n$ odd.

Comment: @Spenser oops, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a standard integration by part trick. Define
$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\,dx.$$
Then, 
$$\begin{align*}
I_n &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-1}x\,(\sin x\,dx) \\
&=-\sin^{n-1}x\,\cos x\big|_0^{\pi/2}+(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2 x\sin^{n-2}x\,dx\\
&=(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\sin^2x)\sin^{n-2}x\,dx \\
&=(n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_n).
\end{align*}
$$
Solving for $I_n$, and using induction (given that $I_1=1$) finishes the proof.

**Added:** Note that $I_2=\pi/4$ and hence the same argument shows that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\,dx$ is rational for all even $n>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2n+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^n}{\sqrt{1-u}}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-v)^n}{\sqrt{v}}\,dv $$
hence, by the binomial theorem and termwise integration,
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2n+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \int_{0}^{1}v^{k-1/2}\,dv=\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\in\mathbb{Q}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

You can start by saying that $$\sin^{2k+1}(x) dx = -(1-\cos^2x)^k d(\cos x).$$
The final result should quickly follow.